# Windows 10 Task Scheduler to Launch Application on Idle After Specified Amount of Time

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-task-scheduler

I'm using Task Scheduler to launch application when computer is idle using the "On idle" trigger.

This works great and all and it seems to wait for 4 minutes until it fires.

Question is: If I wanted to launch application for 10 minutes, how do I configure? I tried using "Conditions" tab but that did not work.

Comment: When you say "for 10 minutes" do you mean that you want it to run 10 minutes after you last interact with the computer instead of 4 minutes? Or do you mean that you want the task to run 4 minutes after you last interact with the computer and then automatically quit that running task after 10 minutes?

Comment: @Worthwelle Yes, I want it to run 10 minutes after last interaction.

Comment: Without editing the idle time or thinking about it too deeply, you could probably have the Task Scheduler trigger a batch file (after the idle) that waits six minutes then starts your application.

Comment: @mael' Thanks. This is pointing me to right direction. I created batch file and using "timeout" command to delay. This works but it opens a cmd window that starts a countdown of the timeout. Any way I can make the countdown/wait invisible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution by following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23557720/execute-batch-file-without-command-line).

Basically creating a VBS script:

```
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WshShell.Run chr(34) & "C:\Test\My.bat" & Chr(34), 0
Set WshShell = Nothing
```

And selecting it as program/script to run within Task Scheduler.